# Execute SET statement before STORED PROCEDURE call

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures, percona

I've a simple C# code which is creating MySQL connection, stored procedure command with parameters and returns DataReader object. Since we switched to Percona Cluster I want to execute this stored proc. with local flag (SET wsrep_on = 0;) so it will work event when cluster is not available. Is it possible to run the statement SET wsrep_on = 0; directly before executing stored proc.? Since it's a session variable does it work with connection pooling etc.? Cheers

Comment: I guess updating the SP is out of the question?

Comment: Updating the SP is not a problem but on a specific node I can access the clustered and non-clustered data - in case of cluster communication failed I need to be able to access local copy of data that's why I need to set wsrep_on=0 and I need to do it before accessing the SP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try executing your SQL in 1 shot like so..

`"SET wsrep_on = 0; EXEC StoredProc @Param1;"`

It works fine when I try with MSSQL but I don't have a MySQL handy right now to test there..

Comment: OK but how to execute it with MySqlCommand object?
MySqlCommand comm = new MySqlCommand("SP_NAME", conn);
comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
comm.Parameters.Add(..);
var reader = comm.ExecuteReader();

Is it possible to replace SP_NAME with "SET wsrep_on=0;SP_NAME"?

Comment: Instead of "SP_NAME" put the entire SQL like I showed you.. and take out `comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;`..